# How to access a private MSMQ queue created by NETWORK SERVICE account?

Tags: .net, permissions, msmq

My application consists of two part: a web service, which sends queues to a private MSMQ queue, and a Windows service, which takes queues and inserts them to database. In my development machine, everything's fine, but when I deploy them to the server, a permission issue was risen:

- The webservice, runs inside IIS, use NETWORK SERVICE account to create the queue.
- the service itself, runs as administrator, and then cannot access the queue.

I tried to add permissions for administrator account, but failed with error "Access is denied". I even cannot delete these queues.

How can I fix this? 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the webservice creates the queue it should make sure that it has appropriate access rights. If you are using .NET you can use the [MessageQueue.SetPermissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5c7ah567.aspx) method to modify the permissions of the queue after it has been created.

This C# code will create a new message queue and give the local Administrators group full control over it:

```
var messageQueue = MessageQueue.Create(path, true);
messageQueue.SetPermissions(
  "Administrators",
  MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add  NETWORK SERVICE and Administrators rights both. at the time of Create queue.

and if you want to delete queue then follow this step...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11430249/672891